# Is it possible to modify the search bar length? + defaultValue doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

Is it possible to make the length of the search bar wider? I am not talking about the actual size because there is a size property, just length.

Also, the defaultValue in Search doesn't seem to work at all, is it just me?
The code I am using is basiclly a copy paste of this one:
https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/search/#types-category
I just added:

```
let defaultValue = "Search"
```

before the render and my Search call is like so (Added the defaultValue part that doesn't show)

```
                <Search
                    defaultValue={defaultValue}
                    category
                    loading={isLoading}
                    onResultSelect={this.handleResultSelect}
                    onSearchChange={_.debounce(this.handleSearchChange, 500, { leading: true })}
                    results={results}
                    value={value}
                    {...this.props}
                />
```

Comment: do you want to increase the width of the search bar?

Comment: can you share the code so that it will be easier to solve it?

Comment: Yes I want to increase the width of the search bar. Editing now but my search bar is basiclly a copy paste of the Catagory one on Sematic-UI-React website: https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/search/#types-category

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

1. set the value attribute like `value || defaultValue` - This will set the default value for the search field if the value is empty
2. Set a class name to the search component and change the width via css

```js
 <Search
        className="search-bar"
        loading={isLoading}
        onResultSelect={this.handleResultSelect}
        onSearchChange={_.debounce(this.handleSearchChange, 500, {
          leading: true
        })}
        results={results}
        value={value || defaultValue}
        {...this.props}
      />
```

```css
.search-bar{
  width: 500px;
  .input{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Here is the live [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ebepZg)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: It does help :) 1 is a nice idea but it's not perfect as you can see for yourself, when you press on the search bar the default value does not erase it self, I will probably need to have the default value in the state and when I press the search bar the event will set the state to "".  2 is awesome, I don't have any css files and I wouldn't want to add 1 just for that, I will look into how do this with styled components, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can adjust search bar length by changing padding size in style.

```
.search-bar{
padding-left:50px;
}
```